# $conf['file_temporary_path'] in Drupal 7 settings.php doesnt do anything, why?

Tags: drupal, filesystems

The settings.php file in drupal is not using the file system overrides the way I would expect and I cant figure out why.  The below settings just simply do nothing at all:

```
$conf['file_public_path'] = "sites/MultSiteSiteNameGoesHere/files";
$conf['file_private_path'] = "somePathHere";
$conf['file_temporary_path'] = "sites/MultSiteSiteNameGoesHere/files/tmp";
```

But if I use drush to set these with something like drush vset file_temporary_path somePath,  it works fine.  However this isnt a solution because I dont want to have to use vset everytime I make a new site.  I want to use a specially crafted settings file and copy just that file and call it done.

Comment: You have the same settings in back-end (/admin/config/media/file-system). Maybe back-end values are overriding file defined values. Try to leave empty values at back-end page.

Comment: That would be a bug if it were the case,  you cant have a working drupal without them.  It would also defeat the purpose of the settings file aa being an override mechanism which is its entire purpose in regards to the conf var.  Beisdes,  everyone knows if you tried that,  it would error and tell u they cant be empty..... Duuuuuh.  Just like it would error if you tried to set it to a nonwrittable dir,  which an empty setting is.